# Prettify prettyPrint() function not loading inside <script> tag

Tags: prettify, google-code-prettify

I'm using Googles prettify.js and prettify.css files hosting them myself. This is a javascript and css script that highlights source code snippets inside `<pre>` or `<code>` tags. Doc can be found here: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md

To initialize the script, it can to be called like this: `<body onload="prettyPrint();">` which works fine.

I don't want to add this attribute to all the `<body>` tags of my pages, instead i want to call it from a `<script>` tag inside the `<body>`, (for reasons a bit long to explain). But this doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        prettyPrint();
        //document.write('doing something');//this line prints
    </script>
    ...
```

The code snippet is not getting highlighted as it did when i called the function through `<body onload="prettyPrint();">` but there is no error on the JavaScript console, and the line `'doing something'` is printing.

How can i call this function from the `<script>` tag?

**EDIT**

Even this is printing but still the syntax is not getting highlighted:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(window.prettyPrint){
            prettyPrint();
            document.write('doing something');//this line prints
        }
    </script>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it has to be called using `object.onload` i don't really know why i just tried a lot of things and this worked. Actually it makes a lot of sense anyways.

```
    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload=function(){prettyPrint();};
        </script>
        ...
```

Comment: It can only pretty print content that has been processed.  Script tags at the start of the body run before any body content has been processed.